# The commutation relation $[H_d, \sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma_i^z] = 0$ from the paper about the constrained quantum annealing (CQA)

Tags: d-wave, adiabatic-model

A quote from the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04212v2) "Quantum annealing for constrained optimization" by I. Hen, F. M. Spedalieri:

> Let us now consider the driver Hamiltonian
> $$H_d = - \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \sigma_i^x \sigma_{i+1}^x + \sigma_i^y \sigma_{i+1}^y \right)$$
> where the label $i = n + 1$ is identified with $i = 1$ ... This driver has the following atractive properties (i) **as can easily be verified, it obeys** $[H_d, \sum_{i = 1}^n \sigma_i^z] = 0$; (ii)...

I don't see why $[H_d, \sum_{i = 1}^2 \sigma_i^z] = 0$. Note that for $n=2$ from this commutation relation we have:

$$H_d \left(\sigma_1^z + \sigma_2^z \right) = \left(\sigma_1^z + \sigma_2^z \right) H_d$$

and

$$H_d = -2\left(\sigma_1^x \sigma_{2}^x + \sigma_1^y \sigma_{2}^y \right)$$

but actually:

$$H_d \left(\sigma_1^z + \sigma_2^z \right) = -\left(\sigma_1^z + \sigma_2^z \right) H_d$$

because $\sigma^x \sigma^z = -\sigma^z \sigma^x$ and $\sigma^y \sigma^z = -\sigma^z \sigma^y$, hence $\sigma_1^x \sigma_{2}^x \sigma_1^z = -\sigma_1^z \sigma_1^x \sigma_{2}^x$ and the similar for other terms. So, in contradiction, instead of commuting operators, we have anticommuting operators $\{H_d, \sum_{i = 1}^2 \sigma_i^z \} = 0$. Where is my mistake(s)?

---

**Edit**

According to the answers below indeed $[H_d, \sum_{i = 1}^2 \sigma_i^z] = 0$. Also, the operators $H_d$ and $ \sum_{i = 1}^2 \sigma_i^z$ (for $n=2$) commute and anticommute at the same time and there is no contradiction (as I have wrongly stated above). This is because:

$$H_d \left(\sigma_1^z + \sigma_2^z \right) = \left(\sigma_1^z + \sigma_2^z \right) H_d = 0$$

Let's prove for the first part:

$$H_d \left(\sigma_1^z + \sigma_2^z \right) = -2\left(\sigma_1^x \sigma_{2}^x + \sigma_1^y \sigma_{2}^y \right) \left(\sigma_1^z + \sigma_2^z \right) =
\\
=-2\left(-i \sigma_1^y \sigma_{2}^x + i \sigma_1^x \sigma_{2}^y \right) -2\left(-i \sigma_1^x \sigma_{2}^y + i\sigma_1^y \sigma_{2}^x \right) = 0
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the mathematical way of doing this (which I'll do in a moment), and there's a more conceptual side to it. Note that the operator $\sum Z_i$ has a bunch of eigenspaces, with eigenvalues $-N,2-N,4-N,\ldots,N-2,N$. The eigenspace $-N+2k$ is spanned by all basis states comprising $N-k$ $|0\rangle$s and $k$ $|1\rangle$s. Now, observe that a term $X_nX_{n+1}+Y_nY_{n+1}$ is a hopping term that preserves the number of excitations (the value $k$). Specifically it changes the state of the pair of qubits based on
$$
00\rightarrow00,\quad 01\rightarrow 10,\quad 10\rightarrow 01,\quad 11\rightarrow 11.
$$
So, you can see that the eigenspace of the $\sum_iZ$ operator does not change under that action. Similarly, the eigenvectors of $H_d$ can be grouped in terms of excitation number. An eigenvector of $H_d$ within a particular excitation subspace is unchanged by the action $\sum_iZ_i$ (because, within that excitation subspace, $\sum_iZ_i$ is just a multiple of the identity).

That should make commutation quite clear. For any eigenvector $|\lambda\rangle$,
$$
[H_d,\sum_iZ_i]|\lambda\rangle=0,
$$
and if it's true for every eigenvector, it's true for every state. If it's true for every state, the whole operator is 0.

---

Let's return to doing things the more obvious way. Unfortunately, just applying commutation properties is not very revealing. We want to calculate
$$
(X_1X_2+Y_1Y_2)(Z_1+Z_2)-(Z_1+Z_2)(X_1X_2+Y_1Y_2).
$$
What you want to compare are the two terms
$$
X_1X_2Z_1-Z_2Y_1Y_2.
$$
We recall that $X_1Z_1=-iY_1$ and $Z_2Y_2=-iX_2$,
so this is
$$
-iY_1X_2+iY_1X_2=0.
$$
Other pairs of terms cancel in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation with eigenspaces was really insightful. How I understand now $H_d$ and $\sum_{i=1}^2 \sigma_z$ commute and anticommute at the same time and there is no contradiction here (I have added some calculation in the question).

Comment: Yes, your edit is correct. However, it is worth noting that for general $n$, not just $n=2$, there is no anti-commutation.

Comment: One more thing about $|00\rangle \rightarrow |00\rangle$ transformation presented in the answer. When I have tried I have obtained something different $(X X + YY) |00\rangle = |11\rangle - |11\rangle = 0$ and I am not sure how to interpret this. Should I apply $e^{i\theta (XX + YY)}$ instead $H_d = (XX + YY)$ to obtain that transformation? In this case $e^{-i\theta H_d} |01\rangle = \cos(2 \theta) |01\rangle + i \sin(2 \theta) |10\rangle$.

Comment: No, sorry, you’re right. That’s me jumbling the Hamiltonian and the resulting unitary. I’ll fix it when I’m near a proper computer.

Answer (score 2):

Since $[\sigma_i^k,\sigma_j^k]=0$, you can expand the first product in $[H_d, \sum_{i = 1}^2 \sigma_i^z]$ as
$$\begin{align}
(\sigma_1^x \sigma_2^x + \sigma_1^y \sigma_2^y) (\sigma_1^z + \sigma_2^z)= & \sigma_2^x \sigma_1^x \sigma_1^z +\sigma_1^x \sigma_2^x \sigma_2^z + \sigma_2^y \sigma_1^y \sigma_1^z +\sigma_1^y \sigma_2^y \sigma_2^z
\\ = & i(-\sigma_2^x \sigma_1^y - \sigma_1^x \sigma_2^y + \sigma_2^y \sigma_1^x + \sigma_1^y \sigma_2^x)
\\=&i([\sigma_1^y,\sigma_2^x]+[\sigma_2^y,\sigma_1^x])=0
\end{align}$$

and the second product as
$$\begin{align}
(\sigma_1^z + \sigma_2^z)(\sigma_1^x \sigma_2^x + \sigma_1^y \sigma_2^y)= & \sigma_1^z \sigma_1^x \sigma_2^x +\sigma_2^z \sigma_2^x \sigma_1^x + \sigma_1^z \sigma_1^y \sigma_2^y +\sigma_2^z \sigma_2^y \sigma_1^y
\\ = &i(\sigma_1^y \sigma_2^x + \sigma_2^y \sigma_1^x -\sigma_1^x \sigma_2^y - \sigma_2^x \sigma_1^y)
\\=&i([\sigma_1^y,\sigma_2^x]+[\sigma_2^y,\sigma_1^x])=0
\end{align}$$
showing that $[H_d, \sum_{i = 1}^2 \sigma_i^z]=0$ as claimed.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. How I understand now $H_d$ and $\sum_{i=1}^2 \sigma_z$ commute and anticommute at the same time and there is no contradiction here (I have added some calculation in the question).

Comment: I guess there should be $i$ in the equations, because $\sigma_1^{x} \sigma_1^{z} = -i \sigma_1^{y}$ and similarly in other places, am I right? But of course, this doesn't change the proof.

Comment: Note that $[\sigma_1^{y} \sigma_2^x] = 0$ and also other similar terms. By taking this into account it can be shown that the operators commute and anticommute at the same time.

Comment: @DavitKhachatryan Thanks for the comments.  Good catch on the factor of $i$, I got a bit sloppy there.  To your second comment, I noticed that relationship has to be true for commutation to hold when $n>2$, but I couldn't find support for that assumption in the paper you cited.  I'll edit with corrections.

Comment: I have taken $n=2$ for simplicity and find that the operators anticommute. I was wrongly thinking that it is a manifestation that the operators don't commute. Maybe $n=2$ isn't the best/right choice for understanding the paper.